# Unable to find org.junit.Test in spring boot 2.7.0

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I am unable to find org.junit.Test in spring boot 2.7.0
I am using eclipse and when I press ctrl+space after writing @Test, I can see only option for import that is org.junit.jupiter.api.Test as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

2.7.0 doesn't support org.junit.Test anymore?

pom.xml below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rishi</groupId>
    <artifactId>BasicSpringExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>BasicSpringExample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I've always added JUnit 4.x and 5.x as separate dependencies.  I don't believe the spring-boot-starter-parent brings either one in for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old `org.junit` package is for JUnit 4.x.

The new `org.junit.jupiter.api` package is for JUnit 5.x.

You should prefer 5.x.  JUnit 4.x is old at this point.